# In Safari, there is a lag for the Open Location and New Tab shortcuts.

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, shortcut

I started noticing this about a month ago that when I hit CMD+L or CMD+T, there is about a second or so lag to when it actually does something.

I verified it's not a memory problem, as it happens after a restart. Internet searches didn't come up with anything.

I'm using OS X 10.10.3 and Safari 8.0.6.

Comment: when you opening new tab, where does it go? (what is your home page)?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I would guess it doesn't matter because it happens with CMD+L as well.

Comment: I'm experiencing this freeze this after clean install of El Capitan. It doesn't happen in "private" mode.

Answer (score 5):

Launch "Console" and have it running side by side with Safari. See if entries about "IMKServer" appear when the delay happens: [image: screenshot]

If you see similar entries try following below: https://gist.github.com/wkrsz/3d5ff7f908a180b87498

Steps from the article:

> 1. Reboot into system restore mode (+R immediately after boot)
> 2. Navigate to Utilities > Terminal
> 3. Enter the command `csrutil disable`
> 4. Reboot
> 5. Open Terminal
> 6. `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false && launchctl remove $(launchctl list | grep -oE 'com.apple.PressAndHold.+$')`
> 7. `sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/Input\ Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/MacOS/PressAndHold`
> 8. Reboot
> 9. You can choose reboot back into restore mode and issue `crsutil enable` again to re-enable rootless mode.

It's originally from Github user squeeb: https://gist.github.com/squeeb/5a9dd082cae1b2d753a0 – I just forked the article to fix a typo in one command.

Comment: I enter "defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false && launchctl remove $(launchctl list | grep -oE
  'com.apple.PressAndHold.+$')" in terminal,it says "usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
-bash: com.apple.PressAndHold.+$: command not found
Usage: launchctl remove <service-name>".I'm using 10.11.3

Comment: @cuthead what's your output for `launchctl list | grep PressAndHold`?

Comment: my output is nothing,in fact I use baidu wubi input method mac and this problem solved.I think this problem relate to OS X Chinese input method.

Comment: SCIM[536]: IMKServer Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (sessionFinished) block performed very slowly (2.95 secs)  here is my console output

Comment: Both of your links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try:

- Turn off iCloud sync for Safari
- Set "New tabs open with:" to "Empty Page"
- But for me, the culprit was "Retab" Safari extension.

Comment: Set "New tabs open with:" to "Empty Page" fixed it for me.

Comment: I'm experiencing the delay with "New tabs open with:" set to "Empty page", or "Favorites", both of which focus address bar and show suggestions. The delay disappears when I change the option to some home page or "about: blank", which do not focus address bar. But then I have to hit CMD-L to type address, and - lo and behold - we have the delay again.

Comment: Tried all above, removed all favorites and read items, disabled plugins and everything I could possibly disable in preferences - no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Include search engine suggestions", Open New Tab (⌘T) is fast again...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a test, not a fix.

Open Terminal and type "nettop"

Scroll down (with arrow keys) till you see Safari.

Now scale the Safari and Terminal window side by side.

In Safari do the cmd+t and immediately switch/watch the terminal window for new connection. It should show established with in micro seconds.

Comment: I will try this when it starts happening again, thanks.

Comment: I noticed the CMD+L with a delay just now. But on subsequent tries, it was fast. Not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: that variation does indicates a network speed variation. we need to catch it in the act :) Just try changing the default window (home) to Google.com and use the cmd+t again. Also just to test, turn off the Extension (if any) in the Safari.

Answer (score 0):

[image]This happened to me. And this fixed it for me.

Preferences -> Search -> uncheck "Show Favorites".

Comment: To my surprise this worked for me, unchecking only 'Show Favourites' but  leaving the other smart search options enabled significantly reduced lag between selecting & typing in the search bar. (Safari 14.1 on Big Sur)