# OS X 10.11.1 with Safari 9.0.1 freezes on opening new tab or address bar selection

Tags: safari, macos, performance

I've got MBPro Mid 2014 with the latest OS X update - 10.11.1.

I have noticed that sometimes Safari freezes for 3-5 seconds when I open new tab or click on address bar. I am sure that I didn't have this issues few days ago.

In system logs I've found these entries which appear just after freeze occurs:

```
24/10/15 21:26:48,048 PressAndHold[334]: IMKServer Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (activateServer) block performed very slowly (2.02 secs)
24/10/15 21:26:48,049 PressAndHold[334]: IMKServer Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (hidePalettes) block performed very slowly (2.02 secs)
24/10/15 21:26:48,049 PressAndHold[334]: IMKServer Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (deactivateServer) block performed very slowly (2.02 secs)
```

I've tried to clear Safari caches, delete cookies etc but to no avail.

Did anyone stumble across this problem?

Comment: 9.0.1 is virtually unusable in 10.10.5. Virtually every action brings up the spinning beach ball. It is extremely slow to launch or shutdown.The beach ball sometimes comes up without any user action.I downloaded Firefox, it work just fine.The problem just started yesterday, a few days after the update.(2009 MacPro)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188726/in-safari-there-is-a-lag-for-the-open-location-and-new-tab-shortcuts/228583#228583

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this issue. I guess it's related to incompatible Safari Extensions. Try disable them one by one.

Moreover you should update Safari. Currently v9.0.2 is the latest Safari version. Open the AppStore > Updates > Update Safari